# Cannot point to the right bundles because of the base

Tags: webpack, angular-ui-router, webpack-dev-server, monaco-editor, html5mode

I have a mean-stack website, and in `index.html` I have `<base href="/1/" />`.

I am trying to follow [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/monaco-editor/blob/master/docs/integrate-esm.md#option-2-using-plain-webpack) to integrate the ESM version of the Monaco Editor by using plain webpack.

I can successfully generate all the  bundle files in `dist` folder.

Now, in `app.js` I add `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')))` and in `index.html` I add `<script src="/app.bundle.js"></script>`. As a result, loading the webpage loads well `http://localhost:3000/app.bundle.js` which points well to the right file.

However, when I load a monaco-editor, it loads e.g.,  `http://localhost:3000/1/3.bundle.js` and `http://localhost:3000/1/11.bundle.js` which cannot point to the right file because of the base `/1/`.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

**PS:** I am wondering:

1. Is there is a way to let webpack generate e.g.,  `http://localhost:3000/3.bundle.js` and `http://localhost:3000/11.bundle.js` without the base `/1/`?
2. Is there a way to let AngularJS or NodeJS still load well files in the form of `http://localhost:3000/1/*.bundle.js` like `http://localhost:3000/1/3.bundle.js`?